# How to add components above createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Following is my `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`

```
<Tab.Navigator
      lazy={true}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: "#9e39ff",
        inactiveTintColor: "#4b5358",
        showLabel: true,
        showIcon: true,
        tabStyle: {
          flexDirection: "row",
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name={CHAT_MATCH_SCREEN}
        component={ChatMatchScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <Image
              source={focused ? MATCHES_SELECTED_ICON : MATCHES_UNSELECTED_ICON}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />....
```

Now I need to add some Text,Button above `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` and after that show the `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`.

I tried adding `createMaterialTopTabNavigator` component in my own screen but it is not visible. I also tried adding the components above `Tab.Navigator` but they won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to wrap my `Tab Navigator` and the custom components inside a `React.Fragment`

So my code looks some like follows

```
<>
<MyCustomView>

</MyCustomView>
<Tab.Navigator>

</Tab.Navigator>
</>
```

Wrapping the entire thing inside a `View` or `SafeAreaView` does not work for me

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your Tabs With parent View

I have shared a working code snippet.

Use this as NavigationContainer

```
<NavigationContainer ref={'navigation'}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRoute}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name='Auth'
            component={AuthModule}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

and your tabs implementation will be like this.

```
<View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: APP_COLORS.COLOR_BACKGROUND,
            flexDirection: 'column',
          }}
        >
          <View>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Top Text on Tabs</Text>
          </View>

          <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName={initialRouteName}
            tabBarOptions={{
              inactiveTintColor: APP_COLORS.COLOR_666666,
              activeTintColor: APP_COLORS.COLOR_BLACK,
              style: {
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                marginTop: 0,
                marginBottom: 0,
                height: 40,
              },
              indicatorStyle: {
                height: 3,
                backgroundColor: APP_COLORS.COLOR_THEME,
              },
              labelStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'MuseoSans700',
                lineHeight: 16,
                ...getFlipForRTLStyle(),
              },
            }}
          >
            <Tab.Screen
              name='Login'
              component={() => (
                <Login calbacks={this.props.CallBacks} data={this.props.data} />
              )}
              options={{
                title: 'Signin',
              }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen
              name='Register'
              component={() => (
                <Register
                  calbacks={this.props.CallBacks}
                  data={this.props.data}
                />
              )}
              options={{ title: 'Register' }}
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
        </View>
```

Comment: share complete code snippet for better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate file for the tab bar and then import that file (tab bar file) into your main screen.

```
export default class Main extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Customcomponent />{/* custom component */}
            <Tabbar />{/* Tabbar component */}
        </View>
    )
}}
```

Comment: Yes, It Works.. Thank You.. I just added style={{flex: 1 }} to parent view.

Answer (score 1):

in simplicity

1. if you have only this one tabBar on your application
   put your Component on top of TopTabNavigation but the both of them should be inside
   NavigationContainer as below

   `import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-
   top-tabs';
   import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

   const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

   function MyTabs() {
   return (


   <Tab.Navigator>
   <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
   <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
   </Tab.Navigator>

   );
   }`
2. Second scenario is You have this navigation inside other navigation, somewhat this is an inside navigation/Nested navigation
   all you have to do on the above code is to add `independent={true}` as prop on your `NavigationContainer` otherwise you'll get an error saying nested NavigationContainer

the codes will be as below:

```
`import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
 import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
     **<YourComponent />**
       <Tab.Navigator>
         <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
       </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}`
```